# How do you install 64 bit SSIS runtime in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: debugging, ssis, 64-bit

I do not have the DTSDebugHost.exe in the 64 bit path and I cannot find any option to install it when installing the SSIS extension.
Googling indicates there was an option to install it in older versions using SQLServer setup but this is not available as it says to download it separately now.
Is this something that can be done?